# Add up values in an array in an array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to add up a specific variable (gq_numplayers) and display it. How can I do that if the arrays are in an array?
I am using GameQ (https://github.com/Austinb/GameQ/) if you don't understand what  is going on.

EDIT:
var_dump ($results);
http://pastebin.com/BSeeWMEb

```
    <?php
// Include the main class file
require '../GameQ.php';

// Define your servers,
// see list.php for all supported games and identifiers.
$servers = array(
    array(
        'id' => 'server 1',
        'type' => 'css',
        'host' => '216.52.148.30',
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 'server 2',
        'type' => 'css',
        'host' => '216.52.143.83',
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 'server 3',
        'type' => 'teamspeak3',
        'host' => 'voice.xenogamers.org:8730',
    )
);

// Init the class, only need this once
$gq = new GameQ();
$gq->addServers($servers);

//optional settings
$gq->setOption('timeout', 3); // Seconds
$gq->setOption('debug', TRUE);

// You can optionally specify some output filters,
// these will be applied to the results obtained.
$gq->setFilter('normalise');

// Send requests, and parse the data
$results = $gq->requestData();

//make total
$total = array_sum(?!?!?!??!?!?);

echo $results['server 1']['gq_numplayers'];
?>
```

Comment: i don't see where gq_numplayers is populated

Comment: Looks like gq_numplayers has to be calculated based on the requestData. If so, var_dump $results and add it to question.

Answer (score 0):

Just loop through the servers and add the number of players to a running total.

```
$num_players = 0;
foreach ($results as $server) {
    $num_players += (int)$server['gq_numplayers'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have $ArrayB inside $ArrayA, then you need a loop.  Loop through $ArrayA with foreach like this:

foreach ($ArrayA as $item) {

}

Inside that loop, you need to add the code to operate on $item.  So each time the loop iterates, $item will be the next item in the array!  You can add them all up with a variable declared before entering the loop such as $counter.

But I am also noticing you indicated this:
echo $results['server 1']['gq_numplayers'];

That is NOT an array in an array.  That is a single two-dimensional array.  So my answer wouldn't even apply directly to it.  You'd have to change the loop somewhat.

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding it yourself via array_walk().

I'm not sure about the $results structure after the requestData() call but let's assume it looks like the sample array below:

```
<?php
$results= array(
        array(
        'something'     => 'text',
        'gq_numplayers' => 1,   
        ),
        array(
        'something'     => 'text',
        'gq_numplayers' => 2,   
        ),
        array(
        'something'     => 'text',
        'gq_numplayers' => 3,   
        ),
    );
$total=0;
array_walk($results,function($value,$key) use(&$total) {
    $total+=(int)$value['gq_numplayers'];
});
print $total."\n";
```